Can anybody provide detail on this ritual to be performed in times of persecution?
Matsyapurāṇa states

वेदनाशे समुत्पन्ने जने जाते च नास्तिके।
अपूज्यपूजने जाते ब्राह्मी शान्तिस्तथेष्यते ।।
Translation: When destruction of the Veda, (increase in number of) non-believers & worship of the non-worshippable occurs (in short when believers face persecution from non-believers), then performance of Brāhmīśānti is desired.[Matsyapurāṇa:228:9]

However, no discussion of Brāhmīśānti was found in the extant literature. Can anybody provide any details about this or any other ceremony performed under similar circumstances ?

In Gītā press edition, there is given a footnote on this adhyāya - इन अद्भुतों का वर्णन तथा इनकी शान्तियों का विस्तृत विधान पञ्चम आथर्वण शान्तिकल्प एवं अथर्वपरिशिष्टादिमें है । https://archive.org/details/matsya-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n915/mode/2up?view=theater

@Bingming I did read the Atharvanapariśiṣṭa, there is a mention of a special yajna to Brahmā before the commencement of coronation rituals. However, the word Brāhmīśānti wasn't used to describe it. Besides texts that deal with śānti-svyastayana don't even mention it, which is why I asked the question. And Atharvanapariśiṣṭa states that rites described in it will yield fruit when performed by Ātharvana brahmanas only. I want something that can be performed by all brahmanas.

I see, I just shared whatever I could find, hoping it might perhaps be of use to you. I haven't read Atharvanapariśiṣṭa
